# How to link a button to a manipulate play

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I am wondering how I can link a button to the play button shown if you expand "Show Animation Control",

So something like,

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}, Row[{Button["Play", ImageSize -> 80]}]]
```

But where pushing the button "plays" x

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A natural solution is something like this:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}, {{x, 0, ""}, 0, 1, Trigger, 
           AppearanceElements -> "PlayPauseButton"}]
```

[image]

or like this:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1, Animator, AppearanceElements -> 
 {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton"}, AnimationRunning -> False}]
```

[image]

where [**AppearanceElements**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0wgomn6-s11b0w) control what type of buttons you can add.